# Right mechanism & workflow for repeated replication of passwords from LastPass to KeePass?

Tags: backup, keepass, lastpass, process, export

A lot of us currently use LastPass for the easy management, access and input of passwords for applications and websites.

Now, there are some people who are obsessive about not leaving it out to a company like LastPass and store it locally inside KeePass/ DB.

There are some people who Sync the KeePass App & DB via DropBox (or other cloud service) and some use extra hashing/encryption/ application of some key on the DB.

Some may even have a way to sync the DB to their Mobile phones.

Now, I could emulate each of this separate steps "manually" and hope that I am not making some mistakes; i.e. Export from Lastpass, Import to KeePass, Correct folder sync, and extra encrypting/ hashing, Ensure the files are not kept unencrypted for long during the process, flush the temporary exported-imported data.

Since, we have to do this repeatedly, what should be the flow (manual and/ or automated/ semi-automated) to leave lesser gaps, in what might be a semi-imperfect workflow.

PS: I use Windows.

What would the right way to do this while not leaving too many Gaps/ password data exposed in the workflow?

Comment: I'd be surprised if someone understood this question... Will wait silently and observe ;)

Comment: @techraf I'll try to add more clarity to it with links and examples that I've read